# Typescript - Calling function repeatedly from within ForEach() leads to undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

I'm trying to iterate through an object that is made of objects, where one property of each object is used to make a service call.

This works fine when I try to do this just once and I can console log out the data returned from a successful service call, but when I try to use forEach() to repeat this process for every object within the parent object I get the error "Cannot read property 'host' of undefined".

Could someone explain what I am missing?

This is an example of what my code looks like right now:

```
getItemParametersCallback(data){
    ...
    // Parent Object made of Objects 
    // data is returned by a service call 
    this.parentObject = data.json();

    // Iterate through the objects of the parentObject
    const parentObjectItems = Object.keys(this.parentObject);

    parentObjectItems.forEach( key => {
        // I can add an if to limit this to being called once,
        // like if(key === 'apple')... and it works fine
        this.ItemService.getItem(this.getItemCallback.bind(this), 
            this.parentObject[key]);
    });
}

// Console log out the data returned 
getItemCallback(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Try doing console.log(this.parentObject) - maybe it's missing some property.

Comment: Not missing a property unfortunately. I can restrict the foreach to 2 properties with an if statement where I know that each property will return individually, just not when I try to do both. Thanks though.

Comment: Do the methods `getItem` or `getItemCallback` mutate the state in some way?

Comment: I don't believe so. It is just a service call to a REST API. I can use it to get back a json object when I specify a single object to run the service call for. Perhaps because the service call is being run, then being run again before the previous one's callback is completed?

Comment: `"Cannot read property 'host' of undefined".` - what is the object that is supposed to have `host`? Otherwise it looks like your doing something like [this](https://hastebin.com/ihijocebow.ts) but with lots of JS stuff like `bind` & `Object.keys`. Does doing something like in the hastebin work instead?

Comment: The parent object is an object returned from a service call that is made up of other objects.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
this.parentObject = data.json();

// Iterate through the objects of the parentObject
const parentObjectItems = Object.keys(this.parentObject);
```

the `data.json` / `.json` method *returns a promise*. So `Object.keys(this.parentObject)` is wrong.

## Solution

Use `.then` or `async/await` to unravel the continuation.

## More

- Promises : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html
- Async / Await : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html

Comment: So something like this then? 
  `const entityValues = value.json().then(data => ({
                     data: data,
                     status: data.status
                 })
              ).then(res => {
                  console.log(res.status, res.data.title)
              });`

Comment: @gv0000 Indeed  